# Are there any downsides to Spark Adaptive Query Execution (AQE)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am familiar with what AQE is and a lot of the major benefits to using it. What I can't seem to find is a discussion of the downsides (if any). Since it is disabled by default I figure there might be some reasons why you would NOT want to enable AQE. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that any feature is expected to have certain situation where it will show its downsides. Spark AQE is no exception. Although one can find plethora of advantages for keeping AQE enabled in Spark 3.0 onwards but certainly it generates weird errors and exceptions when Spark SQL contains some series of INNER JOINS or columns getting fetched from multiple dataframes after applying multiple filter conditions.

I faced similar situation when even after checking entire Spark SQL code, I was not able to figure out why it kept throwing "UnspecifiedDistribution does not have default partitioning" ERROR. At this point after several research I came across the AQE feature which remains turned ON by default if spark session is created. So turning it off worked for me. There is one other guy who faced similar, refer to below blog. Happy coding!!

https://www.mail-archive.com/user@spark.apache.org/msg77017.html

Answer (score 0):

Barring any errors, it is a useful feature in more than one way.

It often confuses people though. Turning off AQE gives other plans, but that is not a big deal - that is the intention. I.e. to dynamically alter shuffling and partitioning strategy during the course of a Spark App. It's been heavily invested in.

See https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/introducing-apache-spark-adaptive-query-execution-aqe-abhijit-sarkhel/ and https://kyuubi.readthedocs.io/en/v1.6.1-incubating/deployment/spark/aqe.html and https://blog.knoldus.com/adaptive-query-execution-aqe-in-spark-3-0/, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/optimizations/aqe.

The 1st article talks about disadvantages but actually does not name any. The other three are on mark.

The fourth indicates an aspect to be aware of:

> Should I still use a broadcast join strategy hint with AQE enabled?
>
> Yes. A statically planned broadcast join is usually more performant
> than a dynamically planned one by AQE as AQE might not switch to
> broadcast join until after performing shuffle for both sides of the
> join (by which time the actual relation sizes are obtained). So using
> a broadcast hint can still be a good choice if you know your query
> well. AQE will respect query hints the same way as static optimization
> does, but can still apply dynamic optimizations that are not affected
> by the hints.